# How to start-up desktop shortcuts when Windows starts?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

1. Is there a way to start-up desktop shortcut automatically when Windows starts?
   (E.g. launch Google Chrome on login)
2. Additionally, is there a way to make the browser start in full-screen mode? (The same as pressing F11)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. simply place a shortcut inside `start/all programs/startup`.
2. Chrome can be started from the command line with a flag:

   ```
   %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -start-maximized
   ```

   so you can simply edit the Chrome app shortcut, or create a `.bat` file and place that line inside, than put either into the folder mentioned above (`startup`).

**References:**

- [how to auto start Chrome fullscreen](http://www.techiecorner.com/1941/how-to-auto-start-chrome-in-full-screen-mode-f11-everytime/)
- [Chrome fullscreen mode on open](http://www.browser-watch.com/2008/09/19/full-screen-google-chrome-on-open/)
- [Windows startup folder on microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Run-a-program-automatically-when-Windows-starts)

Comment: @EliranMalka For future reference, `%LocalAppData%` should be used in place of `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local`. Or at the very least, `%UserProfile%` instead of `C:\Users\[user]`. The environment variables should always point to the correct places, whereas you never know if someone reading your answer has changed their profile paths.

Comment: @EliranMalka The `-start-maximized` CLI argument does not launch Chrome in full screen. Unfortunately, the `--kiosk` argument is wrong as well. There is no in between, it seems.

Comment: @iglvzx, yeah is seem so. please post another answer if you know how to work it out, so others may benefit from it, thanks.

Comment: @Eliran, I'm working on a solution. I'd like to make it cross-browser first. :)

Comment: @Bside I've come up with a solution to launch Google Chrome in fullscreen. See my question and answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/430862/windows-launch-google-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode :)