# Launch Google Chrome in Fullscreen mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fullscreen, application-launch

How can I launch Google Chrome in fullscreen mode from a shortcut?

I have tried the CLI arguments `--start-maximized` and `--kiosk`, but both do not activate the regular fullscreen mode (i.e. when you press <kbd>F11</kbd>).

If only there was a way to automatically press <kbd>F11</kbd> once Google Chrome was open...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Update:

I've worked on a more complete solution based on the script below. It is called **FEleven** and it is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/iglvzx/FEleven

One of the main benefits of FEleven over the the solution below is that I've included built-in support for Google Chrome and other browsers, allowing you to omit the window-title parameter, i.e.:

```
feleven "path\to\chrome.exe ..."
```

---

> If only there was a way to automatically press <kbd>F11</kbd> once Google Chrome was open...

There is! With a little help from [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) we can launch Google Chrome in fullscreen mode. Now, <kbd>F11</kbd> is pretty standard as a `fullscreen` keyboard shortcut, so we will write a script that can work with any program we throw at it! Let's begin...

---

### 1. Setup

So, one little known feature about AutoHotkey is that you can call scripts from the [command line](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd) (and with parameters). We will be [compiling](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) the following script; I named mine `Fullscreen.exe`.

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoTrayIcon
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

Title = %1%
Title := Title . "$"
Target = %2%

Run, %Target%

WinWaitActive, %Title%
Send, {F11}

ExitApp
```

*If instead you would like to maximize the window instead of pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>, replace `Send, {F11}` above with:*

```
Send, !{Space}
Send, x
```

**Outline:**

1. Launch the `Target`
2. Once we have an active window whose title **ends with** our `Title`, send <kbd>F11</kbd> to enable fullscreen mode.

> **Note**: If don't want to install AutoHotkey or compile your own script, I have uploaded a compiled script for you on my server:
> [[image: icon] ahk.igalvez.net/**Fullscreen.exe**, 772 KB](http://ahk.igalvez.net/Fullscreen.exe)
>
> Alternative for maximizing the window:
> [[image: icon] ahk.igalvez.net/**Maximize.exe**, 772 KB](http://ahk.igalvez.net/Maximize.exe)

---

### Demonstration:

Now, you can launch an application in fullscreen by calling the `.exe` like so:

```
Fullscreen "Title" "Target"
```

*Assuming that you are currently in the directory where `Fullscreen.exe` is located, or `Fullscreen.exe` is in a [%Path%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) directory.*

**Example:**

```
Fullscreen "- Google Chrome" "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Use it in shortcut (`.lnk`) or a batch `(.bat)` file!

Comment: Clever! I don't really use the fullscreen mode, but the general idea (open `X` and send `Y` to the window) will come in handy.

Answer (score 9):

The app mode should do the trick: it launches your instance of chrome in a full screen, separate window.

```
chrome.exe --app=https://my_url.com
```

Comment: And I think is quicker than the accepted answer :-) (Even though FEleven can be used for anything, which makes it super useful)

Comment: This works the first time for me but if I resize the window and close and then open again it is no longer full screen.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me using Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m under Windows 10.0.10586 64-bit:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen http://www.example.com/
```

Note the double dash in the `--start-fullscreen` option.

Comment: I ran this from Command Prompt. The first time, it weirdly opened Chrome in normal mode but then switched Command Prompt into fullscreen mode. I don't know how that happened. But then on subsequent runs, it worked properly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Close all Chrome Windows.
2. Open One Window.
3. Click on upper right of Window (3 horizontal lines)
4. From Drop Down Menu - Go to the Bottom and Click - EXIT

Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

From small trail I did the command `chrome.exe --kiosk http://your-site.com` start the site in Presentation Mode which is full screen.

Answer (score -4):

This is what I've found to work... (kiosk mode)

step 1. Right click on the shortcut to chrome.exe and select properties.

step 2. Click inside "Target" (it should look something like this) `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

step 3. Append the following switch to the target (after the quote) 
--kiosk http://www.google.com

step 4. Change http://www.google.com to your preferred start-up page.

step 5. Injoy!